# Spark dataframe get column value into a string variable

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying extract column value into a variable so that I can use the value somewhere else in the code. I am trying like the following

```
 val name= test.filter(test("id").equalTo("200")).select("name").col("name")
```

It returns

```
 name org.apache.spark.sql.Column = name
```

how to get the value?

Comment: Upvoting because of how often I make the same silly mistake in a completely different language.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `col("name")` gives you a column expression. If you want to extract data from column "name" just do the same thing without `col("name")`:

```
val names = test.filter(test("id").equalTo("200"))
                .select("name")
                .collectAsList() // returns a List[Row]
```

Then for a row you could get name in String by:

```
val name = row.getString(0)
```

Comment: How do I do that in Python?

Comment: Did you try col_list = df.select('mycol').collect() ?

Answer (score 12):

```
val maxDate = spark.sql("select max(export_time) as export_time from  tier1_spend.cost_gcp_raw").first()

val rowValue = maxDate.get(0)
```

Comment: For whatever reason .get(0) was unhappy for me. `spark.sql(f"select count(1) from {databricks_table}").first()[0]` worked.

Answer (score 7):

Let us assume you need to pick the `name` from the below table for a particular `Id` and store that value in a variable.

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | name  |
+-----+-------+
| 100 | Alex  |
| 200 | Bidan |
| 300 | Cary  |
+-----+-------+
```

**SCALA**

**-----------**

Irrelevant data is filtered out first and then the `name` column is selected and finally stored into `name` variable

```
var name = df.filter($"id" === "100").select("name").collect().map(_.getString(0)).mkString("")
```

[image]

**PYTHON (PYSPARK)**

**-----------------------------**

For simpler usage, I have created a function that returns the value by passing the dataframe and the desired column name to this (this is spark Dataframe and not Pandas Dataframe). Before passing the dataframe to this function, `filter` is applied to filter out other records.

```
def GetValueFromDataframe(_df,columnName):
    for row in _df.rdd.collect():       
        return row[columnName].strip()

name = GetValueFromDataframe(df.filter(df.id == "100"),"name")
```

[image]

There might be more simpler approach than this using `3x` version of Python. The code which I showed above was tested for `2.7` version.

**Note :**
It is most likely to encounter out of memory error (Driver memory) since we use the `collect` function. Hence it is always recommended to apply transformations (like `filter`,`where` etc) before you call the `collect` function. If you
still encounter with driver out of memory issue, you could pass `--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0` as command line argument to make use of unlimited driver memory.

Answer (score 5):

By this snippet, you can extract all the values in a column into a string.
Modify the snippet with where clauses to get your desired value.

```
val df = Seq((5, 2), (10, 1)).toDF("A", "B")

val col_val_df = df.select($"A").collect()
val col_val_str = col_val_df.map(x => x.get(0)).mkString(",")

/*
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: int, B: int]
col_val_row: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([5], [10])
col_val_str: String = 5,10
*/
```

The value of entire column is stored in col_val_str

```
col_val_str: String = 5,10
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested below is an way to turn a column into an Array, for the below case we are just taking the first value.

```
val names= test.filter(test("id").equalTo("200")).selectExpr("name").rdd.map(x=>x.mkString).collect
val name = names(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`s` is the string of column values
`.collect()` converts columns/rows to an array of lists, in this case, all rows will be converted to a tuple, `temp` is basically an array of such tuples/row.

`x(n-1)` retrieves the `n-th` column value for `x-th` row, which is by default of type "Any", so needs to be converted to String so as to append to the existing strig.

```
s =""
// say the n-th column is the target column 
val temp = test.collect() // converts Rows to array of list 
temp.foreach{x => 
            s += (x(n-1).asInstanceOf[String])   
        }

println(s)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: I see... let me do that